# Storing Offline WebPages in HTML5 other than manifest file

Tags: html, manifest, html5-appcache, offline-caching

I want to store my webpages for offline use.. I know there is manifest/AppCache techniques to store the file in the browser for offline use.. Since its storage size is limited and will be expired, is there any alternative available other than app cache in HTML5?? Also tell me about the vulnerabilities and risks in using application cache of HTML5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "storing offline webpages". Does this mean you want to be able to edit your files on an offline computer? Or that you want to save online webpages from random websites for offline use? 
Or do you mean this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-offlinehtml/.

Could you please clarify your question?

****EDIT****
On a webbrowser you can use: "Save Page As", which saves the webpage HTML, which you are able to open and look at. However this does not copy the CSS file.

Maybe another option is standing on a webpage, "right mouse" -> View Page Source, copy/paste that. 
Or you can try Firebug, which does include some CSS (but you will have to copy/paste the code manually).

If my answers above are completely off the question, then perhaps you mean storing an HTML5 page locally at a user. 
This can be done with cookies or the "LocalStorage" property in HTML5 (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). However on the last option, I don't know if it works for whole web pages.

Comment: So you mean from random websites like www.google.com or something.

Comment: ok.. Is browser caching and HTML5 application cache the same one??

Comment: I think HTML5 application caching is what you need: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp, it enables local storage at the user side, for apps/whole webpages. Browser caching is storing a web-page temporarily so it will load faster. Not 100% sure though, you might want to read the W3Schools article about this.

Comment: yeah, right now I've used HTML5 appcache in my project to save webpages locally.. but i m looking for any other alternatives to appcache.. is anything similar available to save webpages locally in HTML5??

Comment: Maybe with Javascript or PHP. I have run out of options for HTML5. Good luck with finding the answer mate!